# Amazon-ecs - trying to access outdated Ruby on Rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-web-services

I'm trying to learn how to use the gem, Amazon-ecs, with Ruby on Rails and found a project that is a bit outdated.
Link:https://github.com/twler/amazon-ecs-sample

When I run 'rails s', I get this error
Link: http://puu.sh/kviQy/9a70448449.png

This error is probably because I have to fill in the keys, but I am not sure how to do it.

```
Amazon::Ecs.options = {
  :associate_tag => '[Your Associate Tag]',
  :AWS_access_key_id => '[Your Access Key ID]',       
  :AWS_secret_key => '[Your Secret Key]'
}
```

How can I run this application on localhost? And how can I get started in an empty Ruby on Rails project?

Thanks

Comment: are you sure you did not touch the file `Gemfile`? If you have, could you paste the contents here:

Comment: http://puu.sh/kvjHj/2bb4d2192f.png This is an image of the gemfile. I changed the https to http, but that's it

Comment: verify that the gem `amazon-ecs` is installed

Comment: http://puu.sh/kvjZT/27be30baba.png Still doesn't work

Comment: I believe, the issue is; your program is not not loading the gem where `Amazon` constant is defined.. so this error is occuring.. try again after exiting the terminal.

Comment: I commented out the part and it did host the server. However, when I try to visit /amazon I get error. http://puu.sh/kvkId/1a33fb000c.png

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91148/discussion-between-illusionist-and-compsciguy).

Answer (score 0):

It runs great in my system, I just cloned the project:

```
shiva@ubuntu:~/projects/amazon-ecs-sample (master)$ rails s
Digest::Digest is deprecated; use Digest
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.2.5 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
[2015-10-02 06:05:38] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2015-10-02 06:05:38] INFO  ruby 2.1.1 (2014-02-24) [x86_64-linux]
[2015-10-02 06:05:38] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=4008 port=3000
```

May be, you need to verify changes you made in few of the latest commits. or make sure you did `bundle install`

```
shiva@ubuntu:~/projects/amazon-ecs-sample (master)$ bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...........
Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/...
Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Installing rake 0.9.2.2
Installing i18n 0.6.0
Installing multi_json 1.3.6
Installing activesupport 3.2.5
Installing builder 3.0.0
Installing activemodel 3.2.5
Using erubis 2.7.0
Installing journey 1.0.3
Installing rack 1.4.1
Installing rack-cache 1.2
Installing rack-test 0.6.1
Installing hike 1.2.1
Installing tilt 1.3.3
Installing sprockets 2.1.3
Installing actionpack 3.2.5
Installing mime-types 1.18
Installing polyglot 0.3.3
Installing treetop 1.4.10
Installing mail 2.4.4
Installing actionmailer 3.2.5
Installing arel 3.0.2
Installing tzinfo 0.3.33
Installing activerecord 3.2.5
Installing activeresource 3.2.5
Installing nokogiri 1.5.4
Using ruby-hmac 0.4.0
Installing amazon-ecs 2.2.4
Installing coffee-script-source 1.3.3
Installing execjs 1.4.0
Using coffee-script 2.2.0
Installing rack-ssl 1.3.2
Installing json 1.7.3
Installing rdoc 3.12
Installing thor 0.15.2
Installing railties 3.2.5
Installing coffee-rails 3.2.2
Installing jquery-rails 2.0.2
Using bundler 1.9.2
Installing rails 3.2.5
Installing sass 3.1.19
Installing sass-rails 3.2.5
Installing sqlite3 1.3.6
Installing uglifier 1.2.4
Bundle complete! 7 Gemfile dependencies, 43 gems now installed.
Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
Post-install message from rdoc:
Depending on your version of ruby, you may need to install ruby rdoc/ri data:

<= 1.8.6 : unsupported
 = 1.8.7 : gem install rdoc-data; rdoc-data --install
 = 1.9.1 : gem install rdoc-data; rdoc-data --install
>= 1.9.2 : nothing to do! Yay!
```